# Table row as directive displays out of table context in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a table and each row is to displayed using a directive and ng-repeat.

Unfortunately, the rows are rendered out of the table context.

Please run the fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/nu1tu9qL/4/

The directive:

```
.directive('myrow', [function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            replace: true,
            scope: {
                rowdata: "="
            },
            template: '<tr><td>{{rowdata.a}}</td><td>{{rowdata.b}}</td></tr>',
        };
    }]);
```

The HTML:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <th>A</th>
        <th>B</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <myrow ng-repeat="d in data" rowdata="d"></row>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Without going deep into Angular's source code to diagnose this issue, I'd say that this is likely an artifact of the fact that you are using an unexpected element within `<tbody>`. `<tbody>` [accepts only `<tr>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/tabular-data.html#the-tbody-element) (for the purpose of this question).

And so, change your `myrow` directive to be an attribute, and make the template only add `<td>`s:

```
<tbody>
  <tr myrow rowdata="d" ng-repeat="d in data"></tr>
</tbody>
```

and the directive:

```
.directive("myrow", function(){
  return {
    scope: {
      rowdata: "=?"
    },
    template: "<td>{{rowdata.a}}</td><td>{{rowdata.b}}</td>"
  };
});
```

(you could even use `myrow` as the scope, rather than `rowdata`)

**EDIT:**

For the sake of verification of the assumption above, I [reproduced](http://jsfiddle.net/tq4j5ec9/) the behavior with the following:

```
<table>
  <tr><th>Column 1</th></tr>
  <tbody>
    <myrow></myrow>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

and using jQuery (something similar to what Angular would have done):

```
$(function(){
    $("myrow").replaceWith("<tr><td>A</td></tr>");
});
```

and the result is that the inserted row appearing above `<table>`, as is the case in the original question. In fact, `<myrow>` is moved outside of table (in Chrome and IE - not sure if this is browser-specific behavior) even before the `replaceWith` happens.

Comment: You answer indeed works. I cannot verify either that the initial reason for this not working is that tbody expects only tr but it makes sense. Thanks!