# angular table row component in table component

Tags: angularjs

I have a table component from which I want to create table row components as children.

```
var documentsController = function () {};

var documentsComponent = {
   template: '<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 tableDataContainer">' +
          '  <table class="table">' +
          '    <thead>' +
          '      <tr>' +
          '        <td>Name</td>' +
          '        <td>Document Type</td>' +
          '      </tr>' +
          '    </thead>' +
          '    <tr ng-repeat="document in vm.documents">' +
          '      <document document="document"></document>' +
          '    </tr>' +
          '  </table>' +
          '</div>',
   controller: documentsController,
   controllerAs: 'vm',
   bindings: {
      documents: '<'
   }
};
```

Here is my table row component:

```
module.component('documents', documentsComponent);

var documentController = function () {
};

var documentComponent = {
    template:
            '  <td>fl ={{vm.document}}</td>' +
            '  <td>{{document.Name}}</td>',
    controller: documentController,
    replace: true,
    controllerAs: 'vm',
    bindings: {
        document: '<'
    }
};

module.component('document', documentComponent);
```

The problem is that the markup is not correct. The document is outside of the table:

```
<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 tableDataContainer">  
    <document document="document" class="ng-isolate-scope">
        <tr>
            <td class="ng-binding">fl =</td>  
            <td class="ng-binding"></td>
        </tr>
        </document>
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td>Name</td>
                <td>Document Type</td>      
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody><!-- ngRepeat: document in vm.documents -->
        <tr ng-repeat="document in vm.documents" class="ng-scope">
        </tr>
        <!-- end ngRepeat: document in vm.documents -->  
        </tbody>
        </table>
        </div>
```

Also the document is not getting passed to the row component and I do not know why.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Table row as directive displays out of table context in angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28672550/table-row-as-directive-displays-out-of-table-context-in-angularjs)

Answer (score 6):

Kind of late answer, but I hope it still helps someone. Because anything not a `td` or `th` inside a `tr` tag is "too" invalid html, and your browser just throws it out.

Try this (no angular or anything that may interfere with the result):

```html
<table>
 <tbody>

  <tr>
   <td>td in row 1</td>
   <div>div in row 1</div>
  </tr>

  <tr>
   <td>td in row 2</td>
   <div>div in row 2</div>
  </tr>

 </tbody>
</table>
```

The `td` will appear inside the table as you add rows, but the `div` will be moved outside (in case of chrome, before) the table by your browser. Even before angular has a chance to parse the html.

As a workaround, you can use a directive with `restrict: 'A'`, and a template like this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="document in vm.documents" document="document">
</tr>
```